# gnupg-2.2.10 gpg: Fatal: libgcrypt is too old (need 1.7.0, have 1.6.5)

Tags: 16.04, gnupg, libgcrypt

I am trying to install gnupg from source code using the following method:

step 1:

I cd to the uncompressed gunpg-2.2.10

```
cd Downloads/gnupg-2.2.10
```

step 2:

I run command :

```
./configure
```

step 3:

I run command

```
make
```

also I installed the libgcrypt as follow before the previous steps as follow:

step 1:

I cd to the libgcrypt uncompressed folder

step 2:

I run

```
sudo ./configure
```

step 3:

I run :

```
sudo make
```

step 4:

I run

```
sudo make install
```

but every time I go to the folder gnupg-2.2.10/g10 and run

```
./gpg
```

I get

```
 gpg: Fatal: libgcrypt is too old (need 1.7.0, have 1.6.5)
```

now here is the output of ls  /usr/local/lib

```
libassuan.la        libgcrypt.so.20         libksba.la         libnpth.so.0
libassuan.so        libgcrypt.so.20.2.3     libksba.so         libnpth.so.0.1.2
libassuan.so.0      libgpg-error.la         libksba.so.8       python2.7
libassuan.so.0.8.1  libgpg-error.so         libksba.so.8.11.6  python3.5
libgcrypt.la        libgpg-error.so.0       libnpth.la
libgcrypt.so        libgpg-error.so.0.24.3  libnpth.so
```

please tell me what are the needed commands to fix this error? and please note I am not linux expert

Answer (score 1):

Try

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

./gpg

Comment: I can confirm this does make `gpg` run but it's still not great since it appears during the Makefile it's not using the `libgcrypt-config` tool correctly (it complains about the *system* version of `libgcrypt` even when a source version is installed to `/usr/local`)

Comment: Yes, Kristopher. I also think it is not ideal. I couldn't comment the question (joined 2 days ago), only answer. Now i can comment too. But if it will work for the user i hope it narrows the problem and final and ideal solution will be found. Thank you for the comment. Regards.